# Setting up custom domained heroku app to send email from the domain's email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, email

So, I have a heroku app: severe-ocean-4908.herokuapp.com/

The app has a custom domain: www.volunteerhours.org that I purchased through godaddy

I have zerigo basic addon on my heroku app that hosts the heroku app under the domain name www.volunteerhours.org

Currently, the website sends email through gmail, but now I am trying to have it send email using the free email account info@volunteerhours.org

I have done some research online and have found some useful articles

Here are the links that I think talk about the setup that I am trying to do:

1. http://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/creating_your_first_domain
2. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22523/enable-email-on-godaddy-when-using-zerigo-on-heroku-hosted-app

My Question

Currently, I am trying to add my email host in zerigo so that email.volunteerhours.org hosts to smptout.sercureserver.net...like mentioned in the first article

I am a beginner in Rails and I know that this question is not very specific or if this is the ideal/easy way to do it. Any help/comment is highly appriciated

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a CNAME record in the Zerigo interface. The below screenshot on the Zerigo link provided shows where you need to do it.

Set the "host" as `email`, leave the TTL as the default (doesn't matter for your end of the CNAME record), set the type to `CNAME` and leave the priority blank.

The data field will need to be `smptout.secureserver.net`.

Note that you will also need to fill in the MX records for your domain, as per the GoDaddy documentation. Make sure to set `email` in the Host field for the MX records as this will be  your mail domain.

[image: Zerigo DNS interface]

Comment: I tried your setup and this is how my zerigo setup looks like http://www.diigo.com/item/image/2x4sx/9kyh